# Ajax call not going to function in IE but works fine in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I’ve inherited a project that is using Ajax and jQuery to get data and populate a jQuery calendar. I have addressed an issue that needed to be fixed but then I was told another issue is not working. So, I started troubleshooting the Ajax call and found that it’s working just fine in Chrome but not in IE11.

I’ve done some searching and it seems as though IE might be trying to cache results. However, I’ve tried a couple of the suggestions without any luck. The first one was to make it a “POST” instead of “GET” but this was already a “POST”. The next one was to set the “cache: false” on the Ajax call. I added that but it didn’t seem to make a difference.  I also added an “error:” section in the jQuery call which was not there previously. I never get any kind of alert with that code.

I put an alert in the “success:” of the call and that gets called every time. However, what doesn’t get called is the “ProcessVactionResponse” function. I put an alert and a break point in that function for testing. In Chrome I stop at the break point and get the alert but in IE I never get to the function when I’m debugging.

I’m looking for any suggestions of what I can try.

```
if (empid != "" && start != "" && end != "") {
                    $("#ajaxloader").show();
                    $("#lnkvacation").hide();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "EmployeeManagement.aspx/GetVacation",
                        data: "{'employeeId':'" + empid + "','start':'" + start + "','end':'" + end + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false,
                        async: true,
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert("AJAX successful");

                            ProcessVacationResponse(response);
                            $("#ajaxloader").hide();
                            $("#lnkvacation").show();
                        }                
                    });

                }
```

Javascript file. Chrome gets here just fine but IE never gets to this function.

```
function ProcessVacationResponse(response) {

    alert("in ProcessVacationResponse function");

    var vacationdata = response.d;

    debugger;

}
```

Comment: If the issue really is caching and you can't fix it serverside, just add the current timestamp to the end of the URL ` + '&' + new Date().getTime()` so that each request has an unique URL. But there's a big chance that there's a different issue.

Comment: Have you tried using the developer console in IE to see the error?

Comment: I've tried the F12 tools in IE but didn't see anything. However, I will say that I don't know the tools very well.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it's a caching issue. That's just what I found when researching. Most issues seem to revolve around caching in IE.

Comment: I'm still testing some stuff but it possible that it might be the jQuery version. The site was using v1.9.1 and I switched to v3.1.1 and at least I can get to the function now. I have to confirm other things didn't break though.